# Frequency count with multiple conditions R

Tags: r, count, data.table, frequency

Have a data frame

```
Date         Team            Opponent   Weather   Outcome
2017-05-01   All Stars       B Stars      Rainy     1
2017-05-02   All Stars       V Stars      Rainy     1
2017-05-03   All Stars       M Trade      Sunny     0
 .
 .
2017-05-11   All Stars       Vdronee      Sunny     0
```

Where Outcome 1 indicates a win. I have used the table function to get the frequency and applied condition.

```
table(df$Outcome, df$Team == "All Stars")
```

Returns me this

```
    FALSE TRUE
  0  1005   30
  1  1323   57
```

So frequency of win is 57/87 =0.655

Two Questions:

**Rather the calculating the win frequency manually, how do I embed this directly in a formula?**

and

**How do I filter based on the x most recent observations? i.e something like**

```
    table(df$Outcome, df$Team == "All Stars" & df$date = filtering for the 5 most recent observations)
```

thanks

Comment: Is your `Date` column always sorted chronologicaly  ? As it apears to be.

Comment: for proportion table, you can use `prop.table()`

Comment: @kanak is sorted chronologically in an desc order per Team.

E.g 2017-01-01 All Stars
      2017-01-02 All Stars
      2017-01-01 Other Team
      2017-01-02 Other Team

Comment: It's easier get help if you provide reproducible [examples](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started). Welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to use `data.table`

```
libray(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, .(prop=sum(outcome)/.N),Team]
```

to get the 5 most recent observations you can to the following:

```
dt[,head(.SD,5),by=.(Team,Date)][,.(prop=sum(outcoume/.N),Team]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Where is the filter applied in the above formula? I have more teams then "All Stars" in my data frame. The above suggestions doesn't filter for a specific team right?

Comment: It groups by team.

Comment: Is it possible to filter for specific team like in this example:  table(df$Outcome, df$Team == "All Stars")

Comment: `dt[Team=="All Stars",head(.SD,5),by=.(Team,Date)][,.(prop=sum(outcoume/.N),Team]`. Have a look [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

Comment: @DJJ, Please learn how to [format your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)